# How to solve an equation by substituting possible solutions?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I wish to solve this equation for *kappa*, given a certain set of parameters (*m* and *beta*):

```
chi[x_, m_, beta_, kappa_] := (x*(1 - x))^beta*Exp[-(m^2/(2*kappa^2*x*(1 - x)))]

norm[m_, beta_, kappa_] := 1/NIntegrate[chi[x, m, beta, kappa]^2/(x*(1 - x)), {x, 0, 1}]

deltaM2[m_, beta_, kappa_] := norm[m, beta, kappa]*m^2*NIntegrate[chi[x, m, beta, kappa]^2/(x^2*(1 - 
x)^2), {x, 0, 1}]

M2[m_, beta_, kappa_] := deltaM2[m, beta, kappa] + 2*kappa^2

Solve[3.097^2 == M2[1.27, 2.56, kappa], kappa]
```

However, I am thrown this error message when I run the code:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (E^(-(1.6129/(kappa^2 (1-x) x))) ((1-x) x)^5.12)/((1-x) x) has 
evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.
```

It is clear that `NIntegrate`cannot work since *kappa* remains a symbol. My question is if there is a way of solving this equation that substitutes in values for *kappa* to find a solution, so that `NIntegrate` can still work. These integrals cannot be solved analytically by Mathematica, from what I've tried.

I have found that using `FindRoot[3.097^2 == M2[1.27, 2.56, kappa], {kappa, 0.1}]` instead of `Solve` produces an answer, but I'm not sure why. I would also appreciate any different answers! Thank you.

Comment: Make all your arguments pattern test `?NumericQ`, because Solve and NIntegrate are attempting symbolic manipulation. For example: `M2[m_?NumericQ, beta_?NumericQ, kappa_?NumericQ]`. Also use NSolve, not Solve. After doing this I get `{{kappa -> 1.18321}}`. See this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/72682

Comment: @flinty That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.